# PostgreSQL strange behaviour in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, linux, ubuntu

I installed PostgreSQL using:

- `sudo apt install libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib`

Everything is working fine at the beginning, but I need also remote connection,
so

1. I need to modify:

   `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf`
2. but I make backups of them, before modifying.
3. Restart - `sudo systemctl restart posgresql`
4. Sometimes it works perfect
5. but in other cases, when I try `sudo -u postgres psql` I get the following error:

   > psql: colud not connect to the server: No such file or directory. Is
   >   the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain
   >   socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

   It is very strange because, I change just the IP address in  `pg_hba.conf` to allow remote connection and sometimes works with no errors and sometimes I receive the error. Also remote stop working.
6. I go back to the backup files, restart server(so no changes for remote in files), the error remains.
7. I check the service: `sudo systemctl status postgresql`
   Is Active and working.

I have no idea what is wrong, because returned to initial files from backups I expected to fix the error. Please help

I found the errors asked multiple times, but in my case the server is active, and even returned back to backup and is not working.

Comment: "It is very strange because, I change just the IP and sometimes works and sometimes I receive the error. Also remote stop working." -- it is a networking problem

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL server log file.

Comment: @jjanes where are located ?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ why do you think so ? I change the IP in Postgresql conf files to allow remote, so why is affecting host, plus when I move back to initial files from backups the original files are used

Comment: On 16.04 they are by default in /var/log/postgresql/.  I haven't used 18.04, but I doubt they moved them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manage to solve this by the following method.

1. Check postgresql logs

```
> tail -f /var/log/postgresql/<what-ever-postgresql-log-name>.logs
```

If you log is showing `FATAL:  could not remove old lock file` as follow. Then go for step 2.

```
2019-09-06 01:49:13.477 UTC [5439] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
2019-09-06 01:51:17.668 UTC [1039] FATAL:  could not remove old lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
2019-09-06 01:51:17.668 UTC [1039] HINT:  The file seems accidentally left over, but it could not be removed. Please remove the file by hand and try again.
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

2. Remove postmaster.pid at data_directory path. 
   You can check your data_directory path via

   > cat /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf

Confirm your data_directory path - then issue the command below.

```
rm /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/postmaster.pid
```

3. Set permission for postgres to data_directory path. At my case is at  /var/lib/postgresql/ -

> Honestly I am still looking for a (why we still need to set permission) where by default it is already have permission for postgres user.

```
sudo chmod 765 /var/run/postgresql  
sudo chown postgres /var/run/postgresql
```

4. Then restart service

`sudo service postgresql restart`

5. Test whether is working.

`sudo -u postgres psql`

Note: I am using Postgresql 10